Reduce compact solutions
I try the following
Reduce[(Cosh[2 \[Pi] z] - Cos[2 \[Pi] z]) == 0, z, 
  GeneratedParameters -> (k &)] // FullSimplify 

and I get
get k \[Element] 
  Integers && (z == (1 - I) k || 
   1 + 2 k - (1 + I) z == 0 || (1 + I) k == z || 
   1 + 2 k - (1 - I) z == 0)

but the compact solution is
{ (1/2 - I/2) k, (1/2 + I/2) k, (-(1/2) + I/2) k, (-(1/2) - I/2) k}

it is possible to automatize the above  I try
FullSimplify[
 Reduce[(Cosh[2 π z] - Cos[2 π z]) == 0, z, 
  GeneratedParameters -> (k &)], 
 k ∈ Integers]

but gives the same solution as above
k \[Element] 
      Integers && (z == (1 - I) k || 
       1 + 2 k - (1 + I) z == 0 || (1 + I) k == z || 
       1 + 2 k - (1 - I) z == 0)


modified
Your expected "compact solution" seems to be different:
solz = Solve[(Cosh[2 \[Pi] z] - Cos[2 \[Pi] z]) == 0, z, 
GeneratedParameters -> (k &)] // FullSimplify

(*{{z -> ConditionalExpression[(1 - I) k, k \[Element] Integers]}, 
{z ->ConditionalExpression[(1 + I) k, k \[Element] Integers]}, 
{z ->ConditionalExpression[(1/2 + I/2) (1 + 2 k), 
k \[Element] Integers]}, 
{z ->ConditionalExpression[(1/2 - I/2) (1 + 2 k), 
k \[Element] Integers]}}*)

The third and forth solution is shown for odd k, for even k the solution is included in first and second solz
compact solution Mathematica Element[k,Integers]:
{z->(1+I)k,z->(1-I)k,z->(1/2+I/2)(2k+1),z->(1/2-I/2)(2k+1)}

Obviously your expected "compact solution" and the Mathematica solution differ slightly!

@ Ulrich Neumann The solution is correct  { (1/2 - I/2) k, (1/2 + I/2) k, (-(1/2) + I/2) k, (-(1/2) - I/2) k} and is used in the fourth book of Ramanujan Notesbook for the series. $$\frac{\pi  (\sinh (2 \pi  x)-\sin (2 \pi  x))}{(4 x) (\cosh (2 \pi  x)-\cos (2 \pi  x))}=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{k^2}{k^4+4 x^2}$$ Although the latter is not correct, using those same roots I have found the correct solution$$\frac{\pi ^2}{6}+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{4 i x^4 (\sin ((1+i) \pi  k)-\sinh ((1+i) \pi  k))}{k^2 \left(k^4+4 x^4\right) (\sin ((1+i) \pi  k)+\sinh ((1+i) \pi  k))}$$

I wanted to automate the process of finding roots of functions but Reduce doesn't find the compact solution

@capea See my modified answer!

@ Ulrich Neumann ,you are right but they are not compact as I expected, and it seems silly but when you automatically simplify with mathematica and do not simplify the solutions the results are different
